# Xwiki Data Transfer(between two pages)

Tags: xwiki

For example, I have two pages named P1 and P2(created with xwiki)
I have an HTML form on my P1 page (textfield, datepicker … etc) how do I export the data to the P2 page? With IncludeMacro?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing in P1 is not data, but code. If you want to include the (code) content of P1 into P2, then indeed, you need to something like:

```
{{include reference="P1.WebHome" /}}
```

...in the content of P2.

More details on the [documentation page of the include macro](https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Include%20Macro).

However, if your question was about the data that you actually fill into the form on P1 and then being able to store it in the page P2, then it's a different subject. You might want to look at https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/FAQ/How+can+I+create+a+new+page+based+on+a+form. In any case, it would require that you create an XWiki class that defines your data's structure (that you fill into the form) and then, each time you submit that form, you end up creating an XWiki object of that class and you save that object inside the page P2. For that you need to get into some more reading of API and tutorials on https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/DevGuide/

Hope this answers your question(s) :)

Answer (score 0):

https://yadi.sk/i/GuMgJleg3ZHXdC  -> HTML Form

This is the form I created.I tried changing the codes on the link, but I could not perform a data transfer.I want to move the data entered in Textboxes to another page